# how to prevent MacOs to commute audio to USB / HDMI / DP devices?

Tags: audio

I use a elgato USB-C docking station with my McBook Pro 2018 running macOS Mojave 10.14.4

I use various meeting softwares like Skype, Zoom, Facetime, etc...

Regularly the software automatically switch to using the USB audio device of the docking station, and I cannot see it until I join a meeting.

The same issue happens if I connect an audio capable monitor (through HDMI or DisplayPort)

Joining a meeting being deaf and mute is embarrassing.

How can I prevent this behavior?

I never ever use the docking audio device so disabling it sounds the best option, but I'm open to other solutions.

However I need this to be permanent and apply each time I connect / disconnect the docking station.

Comment: What did elgato tech support say?

Comment: @SteveChambers That's not specific to elgato indeed, the docking station works juste fine. I have the same issue when I connect an external screen that have speakers. The issue is with MacOs which commute to whatever audio device is connected. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: The point being that elgato tech support is uniquely qualified to answer that question about their dock allowing you then to apply it to other devices. Whereas here it depends on the technical level of anyone who might have this device. Usually if there is an active user with a particular device they answer pretty quickly.